# type II sum of squares for linear regression without interaction

Tags: regression, sums-of-squares

I have a linear regression with four main effects (3 continuous and 1 factor) and the factor predictor is unbalanced.

I am not interested in the interactions between the main effects. However, I'd like to use type II sum of squares as I want to test the effect of each main effect *after* accounting for the other main effects. Following advice [form this great site](http://goanna.cs.rmit.edu.au/~fscholer/anova.php) however, I can only use type II sum of squares if there are no interactions.

If I first need to check for interactions, for which interactions do I need to check? All interactions with the unbalanced factor? All two-way? All?